# Firestore: Getting a subcollection from a DocumentSnapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore for backend for a Flutter project, and the database is nested to have sub-collections under documents.Here's the structure:

[image: added]

I have the data found from the Root collection, and from there I'm trying to get the sub-collection, but I can't figure how to.

[image]

There should be a `get()` method available but I'm not getting any.

Here's the code for the function:

```
  void _getNext(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
        int v = doc.data.length;
        String id = doc.documentID;
        print('length = $v \t id= $id');

        await doc.reference.get().then((val){
        val.data.forEach((k, v){
        print('k = $k  &  v = $v');
          });
        });

       await doc.data.forEach((k,v){
       print("new k = $k, v = $v");
       });

       await doc.reference.collection(id).getDocuments().then((val){
       val.documents.forEach((e){
       print("another k = $e");
         });
       });

 }
```

And the only response I get from pressing the "Literature" document (from the root collection) is this:

```
I/flutter (13395): length = 0    id= Literature
```

There are several sub collections to this document but the returned length is zero. The other blocks of code work fine when I added dummy data to the fields, but that's not needed in my case.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: As mirkancal answered, subcollections are nested under a specific document. You'll first need to get a document (or at least a `DocumentReference()`) to then get a subcollection under it.

Comment: You should edit the question to show the database structure you're working with.  Right now you are just saying that there's collections, documents, and subcollections, but we don't know what they look like, or which documents you're looking for within a subcollection.  Basically, you need to state the inputs and the desired output, and what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `get()` method for `CollectionReference`, you need a `DocumentReference`.

There is nothing wrong with the current situation, you probably want to use `getDocuments()` since there are no subcollections under your collection, but `documents`

> Notice the alternating pattern of collections and documents. Your collections and documents must always follow this pattern. You cannot reference a collection in a collection or a document in a document.

from: [Hierarchical Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data)

Answer (score 2):

collection() returns a CollectionReference.  As you can see from the API docs, neither [CollectionReference](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference-class.html), nor it superclass [Query](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html) have a method called get().  I suspect you want to use [getDocuments()](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/getDocuments.html) instead.

Comment: It looks like you just asked a completely different question.  If that's the case, you should post a new question instead.

Comment: The aim of my query remains the same, I can't fetch sub-collections.